Php application - monitoring endpoint usage by users
I have a php application based on Php and Fat-Free Framework (also use mysql, influxDb, vue js in frontend). I would like to be able to check which endpoints are used and by which users and based on this have a report.
It is possible to use some ready-made solution? If so, which one?
Can graphana be useful? I am looking for preferably some open source solution

The webserver log will tell you which URLs are being requested

If you are using webserver-level auth, the web server logs will also contain the userid. If you're using app-level auth, you'll have to refer to the app logs. (Which you could then aggregate to Grafana.)

It sorta sounds like what you're after is an application performance monitoring (APM) solution?

You can find lots of example to connect your PhP application with InfluxDB: https://github.com/influxdata/influxdb-client-php/tree/master/examples
You can also integrate Grafana by following their guide. or just using one of the readymade dashboard
